# Hide all other series except selected series. Also display the list of items in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, highcharts

I have searched for the solution which can display the list of items in dropdown and hide all other series except selected series. I have found two different solutions

http://jsfiddle.net/b8chchjo/

The code in this fiddle displays the list of items in dropdown

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Tokyo',
      id: 'Tokyo',
      data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
      name: 'New York',
      id: 'New York',
      data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }, {
      name: 'Berlin',
      id: 'Berlin',
      data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
    }, {
      name: 'London',
      id: 'London',
      data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
  }, function(chart) {

    var $customLegend = $('#customLegend').append('<select id="customSelect"></select>').find('select'),
      $option,
      serie;

    $customLegend.append('<option>Select serie</option>');

    $.each(chart.series, function(i, serie) {
      $customLegend.append('<option>' + serie.name + '</option>');
    });

    $customLegend.change(function() {

      $option = $(this).val();

      serie = chart.get($option);

      if (serie.visible) {
        serie.hide();
      } else {
        serie.show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/philfreo/Nkeep/85/

The code in this fiddle displays the selected series and hides all other series.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function(event) {
          var selected = this.index;
          var allSeries = this.chart.series;

          $.each(allSeries, function(index, series) {
            selected == index ? series.show() : series.hide();
          });

          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'apples',
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }, {
    name: 'pears',
    data: [19.9, 81.5, 96.4, 119.2, 124.0, 166.0, 155.6, 138.5, 116.4, 144.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    visible: false
  }, {
    name: 'oranges',
    data: [119.9, 181.5, 46.4, 219.2, 24.0, 66.0, 255.6, 238.5, 16.4, 44.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    visible: false
  }]

});
```

But I am trying to display the items in dropdown, also display only the series which is selected and hide all others. A combined solution is required.

As Highcharts is a plugin, I am not understanding how to write the code. 
Please help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any kind of HTML form element like a dropdown menu needs to live outside your chart code. The good news is that Highcharts can easily interact with HTML events (and vice versa).

Here's the dropdown I built:

```
<select id="chooseSeries">
    <option value="all">show all series</option>
    <option value="0">show apples only</option>
    <option value="1">show pears only</option>
    <option value="2">show oranges only</option>
</select>
```

And here's a function I built that shows and hides series, based on your selection. Basically, this is the same code you have in your `legendItemClick` event, just tied to the changing of the dropdown.

I added an option to show all the series; feel free to keep this feature if you wish.

```
$('#chooseSeries').change(function () {
    // if "show all series" option selected, show all series
    if (this.value == "all") {
        $.each(chart.series, function(index, series) {
        series.show();
    });
    // otherwise, hide all series and then show only the one you selected
    } else {
        var selected = this.value;
        $.each(chart.series, function(index, series) {
            selected == index ? series.show() : series.hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Here's a modified fiddle that shows these changes: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/Nkeep/128/

I hope this is helpful for you!